# Git merge says "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge" but the files listed are tracked

Tags: git, git-annex, git-untracked

I don't see the files listed as untracked in `git status`, and have even tried to modify one and it does show up as modified in `git status`, so the files are tracked. Why does `git merge` says they are untracked?

This is a git-annex repo if that matters.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    papiers/remcheck/
    "papiers/sant\303\251/"
    photos/android_arno_s10e.bak/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git merge android_mj_dcim/master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    photos/android_pro_mj_new/.thumbnails/1598113434562.jpg
    photos/android_pro_mj_new/.thumbnails/1598163462676.jpg
    photos/android_pro_mj_new/.thumbnails/1598163519218.jpg
    [… edited for brevity]
Aborting

$ git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
papiers/remcheck/
"papiers/sant\303\251/Arnaud/DSC_0243.JPG"
"papiers/sant\303\251/Arnaud/DSC_0244.JPG"
photos/android_arno_s10e.bak/AR Emoji camera/20200413_094232.jpg
photos/android_arno_s10e.bak/AR Emoji camera/20200413_094331.jpg
[… other files from photos/android_arno_s10e.bak/ edited for brevity]
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `git merge` and `git status` please?

Comment: ```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    papiers/remcheck/
    "papiers/sant\303\251/"
    photos/android_arno_s10e.bak/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)


$ git merge android_mj_dcim/master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    photos/android_pro_mj_new/.thumbnails/1598113434562.jpg
        [… edited fro brevity]
    photos/android_pro_mj_new/Camera/20200824_155608.jpg
    photo
Aborting
```

Comment: Code formatting doesn't work in comments. Could you [edit it into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65542153/edit) please? Then others can easily find it.

Comment: Please add the output from following command to your question: `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard`

Comment: Code formatting works in the comments with single bracket, but nonetheless it is advisable to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65542153/edit) a question to add relevant details

Comment: I have added the outputs of the commands asked in the comments as edit to the original question.